# Can a force user use their foot to force choke?

Tags: star-wars

Theoretically the force has no association with any hand gesture right? So technically can a force user lift their foot and squeeze their toes to choke someone?

Comment: Or [roll their tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue_rolling)...

Comment: The dupe specifically addresses the Force user's capacity to choke someone without making *any* movements. Presumably a foot movement would be just as irrelevant

Comment: @NamanKumar i usually imitate Sheldon from the big bang theory when my wife teases me and do the force choke gesture but today i was holding two plates so i had to get creative and then we got into this argument which led to this question